# Does any SQL database / CMS let you edit the data in spreadsheet / worksheet mode? (Lotus Approach did, but it's long dead.)

Tags: database, sql, spreadsheet, nosql

Can you fall in love with a database?  I did: Lotus Approach. Alas, it no longer exists. PhpMyAdmin is not the same. Can any SQL database / CMS let us:

1. work the backend data (the "worksheet") like a spreadsheet, including find-and-replace and copy-and-paste (to and from any # of cells)?
2. design custom Views so you can arrange all the relevant information for each record onto one screen, vs being in a long spreadsheet row where you need to keep scrolling right and left, and perhaps include an image or two associated with each record? (Lotus Approach let me design custom Views by drag-and-drop. That would be ideal)

I want to be able to do what I previously did: manage a complete business in one program - clients, prospects, financial transactions, projects, staff hours, performance reviews, customizable letters, a method for bulk importing clients' data and for "cleansing" that data (formatting it to match our formats), etc, all integrated (a relational database). Alas, it did not work online, and then was discontinued.

For Windows 10, or online.

Can you recommend anything?

Thanks!

Comment: For what database?

Comment: @Francesco, for multiple databases, or one mega-db. For my research (diverse reading: ecology/construction/robotics/mythology/music etc) - to collect/highlight/excerpt. For writing/multimedia - for my websites / for choreography. Some for public, some not (house repair+). 
Websites to-be-made in WordPress(?), hosted by Bluehost, which offers MySQL + (just seen) interfaces. I'll ask about SQLite. I read that there is a WordPress-SQLite integration plugin.  I may try SQLite Browser (DB Browser for SQLite) / SQLiteStudio / DataGrid. Or use MySQL.?
I just now saw Michael's answer from last year.

Comment: Why don't you just use Excel? What's the need of having it online if it's for private use?

Comment: Spreadsheets don't allow viewing one record at a time, so you can't see photos / videos, and if the amount of info exceeds several columns, you need to scroll right for each entry.  Also, my wife refuses to use spreadsheets - for reasons like above - but I think she'd use a database that allows focused views.  I do want the flexibility to work in the database almost like it's a spreadsheet, but don't want to be limited to that.  
Much/most would be for public. The rest would be online so I can access it anywhere (even if my device is damaged/stolen) + so I can search a single source for all.

Comment: If your willing to write your own program say in PHP then you can have nearly whatever you want.  Here's the thing virtually all database use SQL, therefore its just matter of converting what is done in the GUI to SQL.    For example, custom views, a select statement has a list of fields which the user can choose.  Say select a,b,c,d from database;  Now just have a GUI that lets you specify the "a,b,c,d" part.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which SQL database you need to support.

- For SQL Server, SQL Server Management Studio supports these features.
- For SQLite, [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) supports most of these features, including custom views.

In general, most SQL database editors support most or all of these features and will support multiple database engines, even though they're primarily designed for editing the structure of the database itself and not the data (though they do allow you to edit the underlying data table by table). To name a few: [SQLGate](https://www.sqlgate.com/?language=en), [Postico](https://eggerapps.at/postico/), [Valentina](https://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview), [PopSQL](https://popsql.com/), [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/), [Heidi SQL](https://www.heidisql.com/), [RazorSQL](https://www.razorsql.com/), and [Squirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/).

If you're looking to start from scratch, I've used and had good luck with [AirTable](https://airtable.com/), which is in the same vein as what you're looking to do. It's a spreadsheet with a database as the backend. (I have only used the free version, though, so I can't vouch for the support or enterprise uses of it).